# Get proportions of a dataframe grouped by multiple variables in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, group-by

I have some dataframe like

```
df <- tribble(
  ~x, ~y, ~z,
  FALSE,"N",1,
  FALSE,"N",2,
  FALSE,"W",1,
  FALSE,"E",3,
  FALSE,"E",1,
  TRUE,"N",2,
  TRUE,"W",2,
  TRUE,"E",1
)
```

Now I want to group this by the first two variables, then attach the proportion column, so I tried

```
df %>%
  group_by(x,y) %>%
  summarize(count = n()) %>%
  mutate(prop = count/sum(count))
```

But I get

```
tribble(
  ~x, ~y, ~count, ~prop
  FALSE,"E", 2,   0.4
  FALSE,"N", 2,   0.4  
  FALSE,"W", 1,   0.2
  TRUE,"E", 1,   0.33
  TRUE,"N", 1,   0.33
  TRUE,"W", 1,   0.33
)
```

instead of

```
tribble(
  ~x, ~y, ~count, ~prop
  FALSE,"E", 2,   0.25
  FALSE,"N", 2,   0.25 
  FALSE,"W", 1,   0.125
  TRUE,"E", 1,   0.125
  TRUE,"N", 1,   0.125
  TRUE,"W", 1,   0.125
)
```

. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `group_by(x,y)` then you get a grouped data frame by `x` and `y`. After `summarize()`, you get a data frame grouped by only `x`. You need an `ungroup()` before the `mutate()` to produce the result you want.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
df <- tribble(
  ~x, ~y, ~z,
  FALSE,"N",1,
  FALSE,"N",2,
  FALSE,"W",1,
  FALSE,"E",3,
  FALSE,"E",1,
  TRUE,"N",2,
  TRUE,"W",2,
  TRUE,"E",1
)

df %>%
  group_by(x,y) %>%
  summarize(count = n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(prop = count/sum(count))
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'x' (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>   x     y     count  prop
#>   <lgl> <chr> <int> <dbl>
#> 1 FALSE E         2 0.25 
#> 2 FALSE N         2 0.25 
#> 3 FALSE W         1 0.125
#> 4 TRUE  E         1 0.125
#> 5 TRUE  N         1 0.125
#> 6 TRUE  W         1 0.125
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

See also the `summarize()` `.groups` argument for more interesting options for how to handle multiple groups/levels. The number of rows per group matters.

Answer (score 2):

Another way without grouping would be to `count` and then calculate proportions.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% count(x, y) %>% mutate(n = n/sum(n))

#   x     y      n
#  <lgl> <chr> <dbl>
#1 FALSE E     0.25 
#2 FALSE N     0.25 
#3 FALSE W     0.125
#4 TRUE  E     0.125
#5 TRUE  N     0.125
#6 TRUE  W     0.125
```